# save data to table by serialize and php

Tags: php, ajax

i am use serialize to get data from page to another page by ajax like this :-

```
var txtCoursesNamewith = $('#with').serialize();
```

and get it on php page like this :-

```
$txtCoursesNamewith = ($_POST['txtCoursesNamewith']);
$unserializedData = array();
parse_str($txtCoursesNamewith,$unserializedData);
```

when print this array its like this :-

```
[txtCoursesNamewith] => Array
        (
            [0] => qq
            [1] => ff
        )
```

i need to insert this array to my table by foreach, i am try like this :-

```
foreach ($unserializedData as $value => $key )
```

but it store in database like this " Array ", how can i store (qq,ff) on table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode()` function.

```
$txtCoursesName = implode(",", $txtCoursesNamewith);
```

Then insert `$txtCoursesName`  as a string.

Comment: no i need to insert [0] and [1] to new record no in one record

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
foreach ($unserializedData as $key => $val ) {
     //your query   insert into table_name(column_name) values ($val)
}
```

Comment: i used this way :)
`foreach ($unserializedData as $value => $key ) {
//   insert into table_name
}`
and still save as array

Comment: `foreach ($unserializedData as $value => $key ) {
$query_with_customer = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `accompanying` (`accompanying_id` ,`accompanying_courses_id` , `accompanying_name` )
VALUES ('',$CoursesID[$value],'".$key."' )");
}
`

Comment: use `print_r($key)` inside this foreach loop and see what it contains.

Comment: its like :- [txtCoursesNamewith] => Array  ([0] => aa
[1] => vv)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the query in loop or construct an array and execute a single insert query

```
 foreach ($_POST['txtCoursesNamewith'] as $key => $val ) {
   //your query   insert into table_name(column_name) values ($val)
 }
```

Comment: no i need to insert [0] and [1] to new record no in one record

Answer (score 0):

'Array' in dbrow means you are inserting unserialized array.

instead of:
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ({$value})

do:
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ({serialize($value)})